# How to set value for CMutablePointer<MKMapPoint> in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

Im trying to drawn line between 2 coordinate on MKMapView and I have array for keep all poi,
So I have this code

```
var pointArr: CMutablePointer<MKMapPoint> = nil
```

and my question is how to add values to pointArr ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to create an array of `MKMapPoint`s and assign that to your pointer:

```
let lax = MKMapPointForCoordinate(CLLocation(latitude: 33.9424955, longitude: -118.4080684).coordinate)
let jfk = MKMapPointForCoordinate(CLLocation(latitude: 40.6397511, longitude: -73.7789256).coordinate)
var points: MKMapPoint[] = [lax, jfk]
let line = MKPolyline(points: &points, count: points.count)
```

Note that a `CMutablePointer` expects to point to something mutable — if `points` is declared with `let` instead of `var`, assigning it to a mutable pointer (or passing it to a mutable pointer parameter) won't work.

For details, see [Pointers](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-XID_16) in *Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C*.